# define a local and live environment path

Tags: php

I'm using a form to upload files into a specific upload folder.
Now, in my local development environment, the local folder is harcoded in a variable like this

```
$destination = 'c:/public_html/discography/artwork/';
```

Once the script is completed and ready to be moved in the live environment, the upload folder will be

```
$destination = '/home/my_name/public_html/discography/artwork/';
```

My question is the following:
Right now, both variables are hard coded. How do i make it so depending on the environment, the correct path is selected?

If possible, i'd like it to be in a define statement, so i can use it anywhere in my script:

```
define('UPLOAD_ARTWORK', ????);
```

local:

```
$destination = 'c:/public_html/discography/artwork/';
$move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['artwork']['tmp_name'], $destination.$_FILES['artwork']['name']);
```

live:

```
$destination = '/home/my_name/public_html/discography/artwork/';
$move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['artwork']['tmp_name'], $destination.$_FILES['artwork']['name']);
```

wishing for

```
define('UPLOAD_ARTWORK', ????);
$move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['artwork']['tmp_name'], UPLOAD_ARTWORK.$_FILES['artwork']['name']);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your on the right path.  All you need is some way to determine whether the script is being run locally or on the live server.  This could be a subdomain if you're using something like dev.example.com or an ip address ala 127.0.0.1.  Then you could write it like this.

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']){
    case "dev.example.com":
        define('UPLOAD_ARTWORK','c:/public_html/discography/artwork/');
        break;
    default:
        define('UPLOAD_ARTWORK','/home/my_name/public_html/discography/artwork/');
}
$move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['artwork']['tmp_name'], UPLOAD_ARTWORK.$_FILES['artwork']['name']);
```

Comment: +1 this is actually a really good idea. I never thought about using a local subdomain such as `dev.` Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work depending on how you have your vhosts setup:

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
{
    case 'dev.mysite.com':
    case 'localhost':
        define('UPLOAD_ARTWORK','c:/public_html/discography/artwork/');
        break;
    case 'www.mysite.com':
        define('UPLOAD_ARTWORK','/home/my_name/public_html/discography/artwork/');
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not a test like

```
0 == strcmp('127.0.0.1', $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to rely on a hostname, you can use environment variables as well.

Using the Apache webserver, you can use [SetEnv](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv), even inside `.htaccess` (), to add a configuration setting, like your upload path (you can use lots of conditionals there as well, like setting the environment based on IP address, cookie, hostname, etc.).

```
SetEnv upload_path c:/public_html/discography/artwork/
```

In PHP, you simply fetch the value using the superglobal `$_ENV`.

```
$_ENV['upload_path']
```